# How to create a video file from images on hard disk using ffmpeg command line?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, images

In command prompt window i typed in the directory of the images:

D:\SavedScreenshots>ffmpeg.exe -r 3 -i Imgp%04d.bmp -s 720x480 test.avi

The images file are Bmp type. The first image file name is: screenshot0.bmp The last one is: screenshot168.bmp

Example of one image details: Width 1920 Height 1080 Bit Depth 32

The ffmpeg.exe file is in the same directory of the images.

In the prompt windows console ouput i see:

[image2 @ 00000000025624a0] Could find no file with path 'Imgp%04d.bmp' and index in the range 0-4 Imgp%04d.bmp: No such file or directory

Then how should i do it the command line with the correct files names  ?

This is the whole output console window:

D:\SavedScreenshots>ffmpeg.exe -r 3 -i Imgp%04d.bmp -s 720x480 test.avi ffmpeg version N-81045-g450cf40 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC) configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib libavutil 55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100 libavcodec 57. 50.100 / 57. 50.100 libavformat 57. 42.100 / 57. 42.100 libavdevice 57. 0.102 / 57. 0.102 libavfilter 6. 47.100 / 6. 47.100 libswscale 4. 1.100 / 4. 1.100 libswresample 2. 1.100 / 2. 1.100 libpostproc 54. 0.100 / 54. 0.100 [image2 @ 00000000025624a0] Could find no file with path 'Imgp%04d.bmp' and index in the range 0-4 Imgp%04d.bmp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Use glob to consume the directory of images into ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -y -v info -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i '/path/to/directory/*.bmp' -r 24 -s 720x480 test.avi
```

The -y flag overwrites any previous output files of the same name in the directory

The -v flag is your verbosity level. Info will help you see and learn what's going on.

The -r flag is your framerate

Good Luck

Comment: This will drop one image out of every 25, since the assumed framerate for the image input is 25. In any case, it has already been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38514926/5726027) at SO.